# ApplyPatches to input file via IDC

Tags: ida, patching, idc

Anybody know, how via IDC scripts applying patching for input file (i mean context menu: "Edit - Patch program - Apply patches to input file"). I viewed entire idc.idc and didn't see desired function

Answer (score 1):

Look at `patch_bytes()` and `put_bytes()` in `bytes.hpp`, they should do what you need.

You can also look at [this python script on GitHub](https://github.com/erocarrera/reverse-engineering-scripts/blob/master/ida_file_patch.py) that produces a patched file from the patched bytes in the db.